# Source code versioning with comments (organizational practice) - leave or remove?

Tags: version-control, versioning, comments

Before you start admonishing me with "*DON'T DO IT*," "*BAD PRACTICE*!" and "*Learn to use proper source code control*", **please hear me out first.** I am fully aware that the practice of commenting out old code and leaving it there forever is very bad and I hate such practice myself.

But here's the situation I'm in. A few months ago I joined a company as software developer. I had worked in the company for few months as an intern, about a year before joining recently. Our company uses source code version control (CVS) but not properly.

Here's what happened both in my internship and my current permanent position. Each time I was assigned to work on a project (legacy, about 8-10 years old). Instead of creating a CVS account and letting me check out code and check in changes, a senior colleague exported the code from CVS, zipped it up and passed it to me.

While this colleague checks in all changes in bulk every few weeks, our usual practice is to do fine-grained versioning in the actual source code itself (each file increments in versions independent from the rest). Whenever a change is made to a file, old code is commented out, new code entered below it, and this whole section is marked with a version number. A note about the changes is placed at the top of the file in a section called *Modification History*. Finally the changed files are placed in a shared folder, ready and waiting for the bulk check-in.

```
/*
 * Copyright notice blah blah
 * Some details about file (project name, file name etc)
 * Modification History:
 * Date         Version     Modified By     Description
 * 2012-10-15   1.0         Joey            Initial creation
 * 2012-10-22   1.1         Chandler        Replaced old code with new code
 */

code ....
//v1.1 start
//old code
new code
//v1.1 end
code ....
```

Now the problem is this. In the project I'm working on, I needed to copy some **new** source code files from another project (new in the sense that they didn't exist in destination project before). These files have a lot of historical commented out code and comment-based versioning including usually long or very long *Modification History* section.

Since the files are new to this project I decided to clean them up and remove unnecessary code including historical code, and start fresh at version 1.0. (I still have to continue the practice of comment-based versioning despite hating it. And don't ask why not start at version 0.1...) I have done similar something during my internship and no one said anything. My supervisor has seen the work a few times and didn't say I shouldn't do such clean-up (if at all it was noticed).

But a same-level colleague saw this and said it's not recommended as it may cause downtime in the future and increase maintenance costs. An example is when changes are made in another project on the original files and these changes need to be propagated to this project. With code files drastically different, it could cause confusion to another developer doing the propagation. It makes sense to me, and is a valid point. I couldn't find any reason to do my clean-up other than the inconvenience of a ridiculously messy code.

So, long story short: Given the practice in our company, should I not do such clean-up when copying new files from project to project? Is it better to make changes on the (copy of) original code with full history in comments? **Or** what justification can I give for doing the clean-up?

***PS to mods:*** Hope you allow this question some time even if for any reason you determine it to be unfit in SO. I apologize in advance if anything is inappropriate including tags.

Comment: I think the answer really is either 1)live with your company policy, 2)have a meeting with the relevant people and explain how to use source control properly and how much time/money it will save your company, or 3)look for a new job. Other than that, I'm honestly not sure what we can do for you here aside from provide moral support.

Comment: Maybe this fits at workplace SE?

Comment: Thank you for that. I wish to iterate that the thing I'm wondering is whether my cleaning up of new files will introduce increased future downtime and if I should avoid it. There are no documented policies about code practices, and no mention about whether history is to be kept from project to project. I don't have control over current practices and they had been doing this (comment versioning) for years over many projects. They are using CVS as an afterthought to their original way of version control instead of making a complete switch. No new job in horizon for the next 1.75 years :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If copy of some file from another project really means (for this sources) "The point of divergence" and parallel independent evolution of source and fork, than legacy history and commented code are effectively "white noise" and can be easy eliminated on your side. For future possible propagation from parent mentioning of **"bifurcation point" only** will be sufficient in first line of Modification History, smth. like

```
...
 * Date         Version     Modified By     Description
 * 2012-10-25   1.0         ADTC            Created from 12.34 of <filename>
...
```

**Addendum by asker (ADTC):**
I wish to quote a comment in addition to the answer above.

> [...] take the source code, remove the comments related to who did what *(history comments)*, but retain the comment regarding what the source code/class/method does *(informational comments)*. That is what the comment section is supposed to be. It should clearly define what the method is doing, how it is implemented and under what condition an exception will be thrown. – [Wins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385966/wins), [2012-10-25 00:57:57Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053617/source-code-versioning-with-comments-organizational-practice-leave-or-remove#comment17737557_13055669)

Comment: You hit on the mark! I'll accept your solution if nothing else comes across. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using some version control yourself - I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/). Have one branch for "upstream" code that is synchronized with whatever you senior colleague currently has. Then you can have one or more branches for your work. You will have good overview what changes you made using `git diff` against "upstream" branch, you can search history of everything you ever did on that project etc. And this all is automatic, without manual code versioning, the files are always "clean", with all their history available in git.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my question was whether code clean-up on new files copied from another project is ok or will it introduce future problems.

Answer (score 1):

If I am I going your position, I'd prefer to modify the other source code and make it as library to be used within my project.

Comment: That's good suggestion but I can't do that. Besides the company doesn't makes libraries out of anything other than extremely common stuff because of heavily varied specifications from project to project.

Comment: In that case, take the source code, remove the comments related to who did what, but retain the comment regarding what the source code/class/method does. That is what the comment section is supposed to be. It should clearly define what the method is doing, how it is implemented and under what condition an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Yes I do leave information comments in, only removing history comments.

Comment: @ADTC Then you've done the right thing.